# Spring dependency injection depending on request object

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, httprequest

I am working on a web application with spring. The application is configured with a properties file.
There are multiple instances of the application in different servers, each instance has a different configuration file (each instance is customized for a different customer) I am using controllers and services. Something  like this:

```
public class Controller1 {
    @Autowired
    Service1 service1;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/page.htm", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView serve(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        service1.doSomething();
        return new ModelAndView("/something");
    }
}

@Service
public class Service1 {
    @Autowired
    Service2 service2;
    public void doSomething () {
            …
            service2.doAnotherThing();
            …
        }
}

@Service
public class Service2 {
    @Value("${propertyValue}")
    private String propertyValue;

    //doAnotherThing()  will use propertyValue
    public void doAnotherThing () {
        …
        //Do something with propertyValue
        …
        }
}
```

Now I have a new requirement. There won’t be multiple instances for each customer, but only one instance with multiple domains for all the customers. 
The application must decide the configuration depending on the host name of the request object in the controller. So if the customer points the browser to www.app1.com I have to use configuration file 1 but if the customer uses www.app2.com I have to use configuration 2 and so on.

I moved the configuration files to the database, but then I realized that I do not know how to make the dependency injection. The services are linked, service1 uses service2  and service2 is the one who must use the value which depends on the configuration. Service 2 has no knowledge of the request object.

Is there a clean way to solve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create configuration object for all customer as a singleton on spring config:

```
<bean id="customerAConfig"../>
<bean id="customerBConfig"../>
<bean id="customerCConfig"../>
```

And have a session scoped ConfigurationService that acts as a pointer to which configuartion is active

```
public class ConfigurationService {

   private CustomerConfig activeConfig;

   // getters & setters..
}
```

Configure a singleton proxy for this service on your spring config so it can be injected into singleton components. You need to have cglib in your classpath for Spring to create the proxy:

```
<bean class="com.mycompany.ConfigurationService" scope="session">
  <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

And on your login controller, select which configuration should be used by virtual host name and store it into ConfigurationService for later retrieval (remember ConfigurationService is session scoped)

```
public class LoginController {

  @Autowired private CustomerConfig[] custConfigs;
  @Autowired private ConfigurationService configService;

  @RequestMapping(method = POST)
  public String login(HttpServletRequest request, ..) {
    ...
    String host = request.getServerName();
    CustomerConfig activeConfig = // decide which one based on host..
    configService.setActiveConfig(activeConfig);
    ...
  }
}
```

Below is a sample FooController that reads customer specific configuration

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

  @Autowired private ConfigurationService configService;

  @RequestMapping(method = "GET")
  public String get() {
    ...
    CustomerConfig config = configService.getActiveConfig();
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

If your program does not have a single entry point like a login page, you can code similar logic as a filter. Check if an active configuration is set on session, if not look it up based on host name